# Imported DB does not have same content as Exported

Tags: mysql, wordpress, dictionary, terminal, phpmyadmin

I am trying to migrate a local Wordpress MySql DB from local to remote using PhpMyAdmin to export *.sql from local and import it into remote.

Problem is that the imported DB on remote is not identical to the exported local *.sql

For example there are several options_values from the options table that change.

How can I make an exact copy of the DB from local to remote -- ideally using only PhpMyAdmin or even CLI -- I prefer to not use any plugs or other utilities for what should be a simple command.

Thanks.

Comment: You are saying that the `wp_options` table changed between export and import? That doesn't sound right. Are you certain that the table on local didn't change after you performed the export?

Comment: I agree.  It doesn't sound right at all.  But after using PhpMyAdmin to export the local dev DB and then remote PhpMyAdmin to import the resulting *.sql file to the production WP server, there are a number of irregularities in the child theme.  This forced me to look into it.  And if I export both local and remote DBs and run a diff on them in VSC sure enough there are differences -- specifically with the tables for managing child theme customizations.

Comment: Did you look at logs to make sure there wasn't an error during import? As well, I tend to drop all the tables then import to avoid similar issues. (just make sure you backup)

Comment: Have you tried remote import (a complete import into an empty database), remote export, compare *before* using remote wordpress? I could imagine that some plugin (e.g. the wordpress file/theme) does some changes to your database when you run the theme.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no errors.  Immediately after uploading to remote, I download it again, and run a diff between local and remote (which except for domains, should be identical).  Here is an example:

== Local ln5686: (94, 'auto_plugin_theme_update_emails', 'a:0:{}', 'no'), ==
== Remote ln 5673: (94, 'auto_plugin_theme_update_emails', 'a:1:{s:27:\"js_composer/js_composer.php\";s:5:\"6.8.0\";}', 'no'), ==

Comment: *"which except for domains, should be identical"*. No, if you run something to adjust the domains in the database, whatever that is may change other things in the data (e.g. plugin values). We don't really know what you do exactky, but as soon as wordpress itself does something, it is more than you are telling us.